# react storybook left panel name configuration

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I configured my storybook and in my `config.js` I have:

```
addDecorator(
  withOptions({
    /**
     * name to display in the top left corner
     * @type {String}
     */
    name: 'Testing Storybook',
    /**
     * URL for name in top left corner to link to
     * @type {String}
     */
    url: '#',
  }),
);
```

But the name is not reflecting when I launch the storybook. It shows default "**storybook**" as the name. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do so is by using `addParameters`. That is

```
import { addParameters, configure } from '@storybook/react';

addParameters({
  options: {
    name: 'Custom-Name',
  }
});
```

Refer to the [docs](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/next/addons/options) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to register it in addons js. It worked :)